# How to customize Google Place API Autocomplete Support Fragment

Tags: android, mobile, google-places-api

I am using Google Place API Autocomplete Support Fragment for my Android mobile application. But as you can from the photo, the autocomplete support fragment's design is not uniform with my other elements' style.

[how my app looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwloS.png)

my xml code:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cv_place_picker"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_box"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_incident_place_ques">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="2dp">

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/autocomplete_support_fragment"
                    android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

How to customize it?

I tried to google for the solution. But none of them helped.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You cannot customize it if the library doesn't provide any customization methods. You have to create your own fragment with your UI and customized logic